# Algorithm for approximating linear-interpolated curve

Tags: linear, algorithms, approximation, interpolation

### Goal

Given a curve defined by a set of (x, y) coordinates with linear interpolation, we want to find the best approximation using a smaller set of points (w/ linear interpolation) that fall along a predefined grid. The number of points and the grid are chosen up front and are static. The following invariants must be held:

1. Our approximation must not go below the original curve at any point. (Both curves are generated by sorting by the x-axis values and drawing lines between neighbors).
2. The grid origin is (0, 0) and generated from an x-step and y-step values.
3. Our approximation must fully cover the original curve.  This means that our first (x1) and last (x2) x-axis values are forced by the set of (x, y) coordinates of the original curve and x-axis step, and that our possible y-axis values are bounded below by the minimum y-step multiple that is >= min y-axis value found in the original curve (derived from first invariant).
4. Y-axis values must fall between [0, 255].
5. The best approximation will be the one that has the smallest area between the approximation and original curve.

### Example

```py
# Example arguments provided to algorithm
# curve - Contains 25 points, sorted by x-axis ascending, w/ linear interpolation between neighbors
original_curve = [(450, 38), (462.5, 28), (481.25, 28), ..., (887.5, 22)]
# Our answer must use points that fall along the grid generated by the below steps
x_step = 25
y_step = 1
# Number of points allowed in the approximation
num_points = 5

# We can compute the following boundaries based on the arguments
max_x_on_grid = 900
min_x_on_grid = 450
max_y_on_grid = 255
# The full dataset is not shown above, but the minimum y-axis value is 9, which is equal to a multiple of y_step
min_y_on_grid = 9

# We want our approximation to use 5 points, which means we can immediately determine the following
answer = [(450, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (900, ?)]
```

### What I've tried

Originally I thought I might be able to do an exhaustive search, but the number of possibilities is way too high.

```
Number of possible x-axis selections = C(22, 3)
Number of possible y-axis selections = P(245, 5) (w/ replacement)
Number of possibilities = C(22, 3) * P(245, 5) = 1540 * 882,735,153,125 = 1.3594121e+15
```

I'm certain there is a more intelligent algorithm I could use.  I've implemented the genetic algorithm before, and I imagine it would get a good result, but I would like to get the best result. I've tried to play with the idea of starting at the max_y_on_grid and doing some type of search + backtracking from there, but I thought I would ask in case anyone has already done this.

Comment: I can't make any sense of (2) because of the ambiguity of having two (or more) "x-axes" and "y-axes" for a "curve."  Could you clarify? Do you specify the origin of your grid or not?  How general is this "curve:" must it graph a function or not?  Could it cross itself?  What does "go below" mean?

Comment: @whuber I've edited the question to include some more information. I agree the way I worded invariant #2 was confusing.  I've included that the origin is (0, 0), and that both our approximation and original curve will have distinct x-axis values, and that linear interpolation happens between neighbors after sorting by x-axis.  This means neither curve can cross itself. I wish I had a mathematically exact way to define "go below", but for now I mean that no interior point of the line segments of the approximation are allowed to intersect with the line segments of the original curve.

Comment: Thank you.  It sounds like your curve is intended to be the graph of a function.  "Above" simply means at every possible $x,$ the approximation has a $y$ value at least as great as the original curve.  Minimizing the area between them is then equivalent to minimizing the area between the approximation and the x-axis subject to the approximation lying in the epigraph of the original curve (the region of points above it).

Answer (score 0):

Due to time constraints and our inability to come up with a better solution, we ended up using the genetic algorithm to compute our approximation.  It was able to generate a better approximation then any of our other attempts, and it did so efficiently (rust implementation took 1-15 seconds).  Here is a list of the genetic parameters we used if anyone is curious.

```
Population size: 1000
Mutation Rate: 1%
Elitism: 10%
Selection: Tournament
    Tournament size: 4
    Tournament probability: 0.75
```